# ensuring HTML emails always show images

Tags: html, image, email

I have an email sent out in in my application, and in the HTML of that email, i have an `<img>` tag which is an image and a link.

The problem is that in most cases the image doesn't load in emails, unless you enable the viewing of embedded images.

That image is an important part of the email. Is there any way I can replace the image tag with something else which always loads in emails? The desire is that users don't have to explicitly click on show pictures to see it.

Comment: you can "replace" the image with really good alt-text.

Comment: You could try using data urls. I haven't tested though, so it's up to you. :P

Comment: Most users are very aware of this behavior.  If the email comes from a trusted source, they are used to clicking on "show images."  At least I am.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely... you can embed the image as an attachment, and then use the CID header in the mail [MIME](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2387.html) to reference it (instead of a URL to a web resource)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to guarantee that an image will be displayed without explicit permission of the user. That would circumvent the whole concept if it were possible. The idea is to protect the user from exposure to undesirable content. In the event you were to find some hack way around it, it would be considered just that, and could get you blacklisted once the hack is discovered.

Answer (score 1):

Is the `img` tag just a reference to an external image that's hosted somewhere?  You could try adding it to the email as an [embedded resource](http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/4.4.aspx) and see if that helps.  Some mail clients may still ask permission before displaying it, though.  But it should get more of the target audience.

Comment: Which clients do you know that still ask?  Exchange/Outlook, Hotmail, Thunderbird don't (or don't by default)... nor does webmail software: Horde, roundcube

Comment: @Rudu: Fair enough, that may have just been assumption on my part.  I guess it's mostly external resources that aren't loaded by default.  Updated the answer.